# Cannot declare Signal in baseclass

Tags: qt, symbian, signals, nokia, qobject

I am having a class A, parent of class B and class C. I have signals: declared and used in class B and class C. But when i try to write other signals: in class A, its giving me **vtable reference** errors. I am not able to write the Q_OBJECT macro in .h file, which result in error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided any code I will just make a wild guess.

Undefined reference to `vtable kind of errors usually stem from moc compiler not generating code.

I am just guessing that you need to re-run qmake.

Also make sure that this file is included to HEADERS section of your .pro file.

Comment: This is correct, every time you add the Q_OBJECT macro to a class you need to re-run qmake.

Comment: Problem is that when i write signal method,  i am getting error that the method is not defined. compiler is not treating it as a signal, but as an instance method.